# Adding Facebook share button not showing up

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I went through the facebook documentation found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/), but my share button still isn't showing up.

I added this directly beneath the body tag in my `_layout.cshtml` page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
script
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            status: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
script
```

(I removed the less than/greater than around the script tag in order to get the code block to show up on SO)

And I added this to my homepage for testing purposes:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://myurl.com" data-width="50px" data-type="button_count">Share</div>
```

I have to add in the text for the div element just to "see" the "Share" text.

Where am I going wrong? I figured adding the facebook widget thing would provide the facebook image/icon and share count, am I wrong?

Comment: Does `data-href` specify a working URL accessible from the Internet?

Comment: Yes, I've tested the URL straight from a <a href="">Share on Facebook</a> and it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ugh, stupid AdBlocker/Avast anti-virus software...

Comment: lol XD ............. oh god! well anyways, that was helpful, I have it on myself. Now I see why adblocking can have drawbacks